# "iCloud Keychain Was Reset" after every reboot

Tags: icloud, keychain, reboot

Everytime I reboot my mac (10.9.5), I get a notice that "iCloud Keychain Was Reset". I can set it up again without problems, but I shouldn't have to keep setting it up. What's going on?